# Overscan Compensation Disabled

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 12.04, settings

A fresh install of 12.04. I need to compensate for overscan, but the setting is disabled for one of my monitors. Not sure why and not sure what I can do aboot it. Is there any way I can enable the Overscan Compensation slider?

Comment: Can you give us the model numbers on the monitors and the graphic card(s)?

Comment: I was able to configure my HDTV to use its "native" resolution, instead of "theater" mode. It is a Toshiba. I still don't know the cause of the overscan disable on 12.04.

Answer (score -1):

```
sudo apt-get install nvtv
```

Then alt-F2 "nvtv"
and then select monitors>overscan
and then set it to 0

Comment: Tried this did not work nvtv package installed but says unsupported graphics card, I have Geforce 310HD.